# MySQL WHERE LIKE by word with comma

Tags: mysql

How do I display result by `SELECT ... WHERE LIKE` with word field?

I've tried this `SELECT * FROM tbl_question WHERE word LIKE '%How are you?%'` but it doesn't work.

**tbl_question**

```
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| question_id | question          | word       |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| 1           | How are you?      | How        |
| 2           | What's your name? | What, name |
| 3           | Hi there!         | Hi         |
| 4           | Hi, How are you?  | Hi, How    |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Example : If I search `"How are you?"`, It will display results by 2 rows like :

```
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| question_id | question          | word       |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| 1           | How are you?      | How        |
| 4           | Hi, How are you?  | Hi, How    |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
```

or if I `"Your name is?"` it will display result like :

```
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| question_id | question          | word       |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| 2           | What's your name? | What, name |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Comment: See normalization.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp  this way

```
select * from my_table where question REGEXP 'How|are|you|';
```

Comment: What if I input "How are you?" on my search form it will send as original text How can I use your code?

Comment: use server side code  for build a dinamic generated sql .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_question WHERE question LIKE '%How are you?%'
```

Comment: Thanks, But I want to use `WHERE word`

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM tbl_question WHERE word LIKE '%How are you?%'

By this your database will try to 'give you back' all the data that begin exactly with the sentence How are you? and as i see in the word you just have only specific words.

I created your table and inserted data into it and i use the query

```
 SELECT 
       question FROM Custom WHERE word LIKE '%What%'
```

so it gave me back your second question.

If you can, explain to me what exactly you want to display.

Comment: Example: I input "How are you?" on my html search form and submit to search by word column to get results.

Comment: You should store always the first word from the input into a string and use the query : 
           SELECT 
       question FROM Custom WHERE word LIKE '%custom_word%'

Answer (score 0):

You are taking wrong column name.please replace it with question.try this.`SELECT  * FROM tbl_question WHERE question LIKE %How are you%`

Comment: Thanks, But I'm not taking wrong I know that I should replace it with question column but I have to use word column.